# Understanding "max_wal_size" and "min_wal_size" parameters default values from postgresql.conf file

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.5, write-ahead-logging

Default values are, according to [documentation for `min_wal_size` and `max_wal_size` parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html):

For `max_wal_size`: `The default is 1 GB`
For `min_wal_size`: `The default is 80 MB`

Then I look this parameters from my database config:

```
select name, setting, unit 
from pg_settings 
where name in ('min_wal_size', 'max_wal_size')
```

Gives result:

```
name         |  setting | unit
----------------------------------
max_wal_size | 64       | 
min_wal_size | 5        |
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Why these values doesn't match default values, which are shown in docs? I never changed config settings at all.

2) Why `unit` column is empty/NULL for these parameters? What means 64 and 5 values in this case? `MB`? `GB`? Or what?

Why this is not like  for example  `work_mem` parameter, when everything is clear:

```
name         | setting  | unit
----------------------------------
work_mem     | 4096     | kB
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are 16 MB WAL segments by default. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL)

> The system physically divides this sequence into WAL segment files,
>   which are normally 16MB apiece (although the segment size can be
>   altered when building PostgreSQL)

So, it's just default values as advertised:

```
select name, setting, setting::int * 16 || 'MB' AS setting_in_mb
from pg_settings 
where name in ('min_wal_size', 'max_wal_size');
```

`unit` in `pg_settings` is present when it's an actual base unit like *second* or *MB*. In this case the "unit" would be "WAL segments", which can be configured before compiling Postgres. The `unit` column is just NULL for those.

Answer (score 6):

2021 Update:

In a Postgres 12.3 setup, this query now returns with units:

```
select name, setting, unit 
from pg_settings 
where name in ('min_wal_size', 'max_wal_size');
```

Result:

```
     name     | setting | unit
--------------+---------+------
 max_wal_size | 1024    | MB
 min_wal_size | 80      | MB
(2 rows)
```

Additionally, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-MAX-WAL-SIZE) states that:

> If this value is specified without units, it is taken as megabytes. The default is 1 GB.