# How to increase Postgres WAL size?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.7

I keep getting the message:

`HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".`

So, I updated the following parameters and reloaded the configuration.

```
checkpoint_timeout = 30min
max_wal_size = 2GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
```

However, the WAL size stays at 16MB.  What did I miss?

Btw, I use repmgr for replication `wal_level = replica`.

Comment: The 16MB is the size of the wal segment size - see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151440/34007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max_wal_size` controls the total size of all WAL segments, not the size of each segment.

So with a value of 2GB, you are saying that about 128 of those segments can be created before they get re-used.

The hint is about increasing the total number of files (hence the mentioning of `max_wal_size`), it's **not** about the size of each segment (file).

---

Up to Postgres 10, the size of each segment is fixed to 16MB

Starting with Postgres 11, you can change the size of each segment but only when you [initialize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) a new [database cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) (but again: that's not what that hint is about).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.

One more question: Does `wal_keep_segments` override `max_wal_size`?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the "title"...

Particular WAL file size can also be changed since PostgreSQL 11 not only using `initdb` command when creating cluster, but also later when cluster is already running using `pg_resetwal` command.

1. Check current WAL file size setting (default is 16 MB).

   a) Using parameter.

   `psql -c "show wal_segment_size"`

   b) Check actual WAL file size.

   `ls -lh $PGDATA/pg_wal/`

   c) With select.

   `SELECT name, size FROM pg_ls_waldir() where name not like '%history' and name not like '%backup';`
2. Stop PostgreSQL cluster (on Red Hat).

   `systemctl stop postgresql-15.service`
3. Change WAL file size.

   `pg_resetwal -D $PGDATA --wal-segsize=64`

   Size is in MB. Default is 16. Parameter can be set between 1 and 1024.

   Note: Command on Red Hat 8 is at path: /usr/pgsql-15/bin/pg_resetwal
4. Start PostgreSQL cluster (on Red Hat).

   `systemctl start postgresql-15.service`
5. Repeat step 1 and to see new WAL file setting.

Additional info:

- [official PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html) search for "wal-segsize"
- [The WAL segment size becomes changeable in PostgreSQL 11](https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/the-wal-segement-size-becomes-changeable-in-postgresql-11/)